# Making a network activity monitor visible in Mac OS X

Tags: ios, macos

In Apple `iOS` you can do:

```
UIApplication* myApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
myApplication.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

How do you do this in `Mac OS X`?

Comment: Where is the activity indicator in MacOSX?

Answer (score 2):

There's no network activity indicator in Mac OS X. Therefore there's no corresponding method.

You could use an [NSProgressIndicator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsprogressindicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with its style set to `NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle`, and position it in your view yourself.